# jQuery Select Elements with a certain CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, position, fixed

I'm trying to add a bit of jQuery code to all elements that have position:fixed set on them. Is this sort of thing possible? It would be very helpful if there is, so I don't have to go through all my code and an extra class to the objects that are fixed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This one should cover all cases:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("position") === 'fixed';
});
```

Not as fast as qwertymk's answer, but also work if the css property is inherited from another rule, as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/Nf4HK/1/).

Comment: I just was about to post this same exact code, as I ran into it while messing with his code and did the same thing as you, and it worked. Perfectly, thank you so much

Comment: @mgibsonbr: A better answer than mine. +1

Answer (score 4):

Faster and safer than Colin's answer:

```
$('*').filter(function(){ return this.style && this.style.position === 'fixed'; });
```

More about [jQuery filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: just curious to know what is  returned when `this.style` and `this.style.position==='fixed' ` are  written seperately ?

Comment: @MegaRacer it's a protective check, if `this.style` is `undefined` `this.style.position` will throw an error `Cannot read property position of undefined` since the compiler checks left to right, if `this.style === undefined` it will fail the expression before the `&&` not causing an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only checking for `display: none` and other `display` properties. You could use the CSS selector `:visible` in your usual jQuery selections, like this:

```
$('.items:visible')
```

Or to select the hidden elements:

```
$('.items:hidden')
```