# How to get all elements with a certain CSS property and change it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get all elements (all divs) in a page with CSS property `position:fixed;` and remove or change that property.

Is that possible with JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: @Vohuman Hahaha! Well that is very nice to hear! Now woud you by any chance know how to acomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Select Elements with a certain CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255312/jquery-select-elements-with-a-certain-css)

Comment: You can use **each()** (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to go through all the div, than use **css()** (http://api.jquery.com/css/) to read the div properties.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You can select the `div` elements using `document.querySelectorAll` method and then filter the elements that have fixed position:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div'), function(el) {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(el).position === 'fixed') {
       // el.style.position = 'relative';
    }
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @GuillermoCarone You are very welcome! :)

Comment: @Vohumna Hhmm... I tested the code with an alert and it definitely finds the divs with `position:fixed`, however when I try to change that property I get the following error: 

Uncaught NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'position' property on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'position' property is read-only.

Any idea why?

Comment: @GuillermoCarone How exactly do you try to change the property value? Can you post the snippet? And have you tried the commented snippet of the above answer?

Comment: I was trying to change the property value with the following 

`window.getComputedStyle(el).position = "absolute";`

probably not the way to go right? :S

I really need to sit down and study my JS...

Comment: @GuillermoCarone Yes, that property is read-only. Using `style` property you can reset the property value.

Comment: You mean something like `window.getComputedStyle(el).style.position = "absolute";` ?

Comment: No, I mean `el.style.position = 'absolute';`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with jquery **[each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each)** and **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** functions :

**Js code :**

```
$('div').each(function(){ //loop over all the divs

     //Condition for the div with style propriety position:fixed;
     if($(this).css('css('position')=="fixed"){
          //Do the change you want
     }
})
```

Comment: A small typo **funvtion** should be **function** :D

Comment: Thanks @highqweb, updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be done, just not very efficiently. @Vohuman implements this nicely in plain javascript. I recommend taking a look at this similar post which has answers that are implemented in jQuery as well [Select all elements that have a specific CSS, using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

you have to get all elements in a node collection with the method "querySelectorAll" likes this:

```
var divCollection = document.querySelectorAll('div');
```

Then you have to check with a loop for the element state like this:

```
    for(var i=0; i<divCollection.length;i++){
       var elementState = $(divCollection[i]).css('position');
       console.log(elementState);
    }
```